# Python error setting an array element with a sequence for different loops

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, indexing

My code is as follows (there's about 100 lines before of setting values for the loop which seem to be working so I've just included necessary values):

```
fraction=np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
tauC=np.array([30.,300.,100000.])

dC_memory=np.zeros((1,3))
dC_frac=np.zeros((1,3))    

for j in range(0,ens_num):

    dC_memory=np.zeros((1,3))
    for n in range(0,N-1):


                # C02 Concentration

                for m in range(0,3):

                    dC_frac[m]=fraction[m]*E[j,n+1]-dC_memory[m]/(tauC[m])
                    dC_memory[m]=dC_memory[m]+dC_frac[m]*dt
                    dC[j,n]=dC[j,n]+dC_frac[m]*dt



                C[j,n+1]=C[j,n]+dC[j,n]

                # Temperature

                dT[j,n]=((T2eq*math.log(C[j,n+1]/Cpi)/math.log(2))-T[j,n])*(dt/tauT)
                T[j,n+1]=T[j,n]+dT[j,n]

                # Adaptation

                dTadp[j,n]=(T[j,n]-Tadp[j,n])*dt/tauA
                Tadp[j,n+1]=Tadp[j,n]+dTadp[j,n]
                Tdiff[j,n+1]=0.5*(abs(T[j,n]-Tadp[j,n+1])+T[j,n]-Tadp[j,n+1])



                if yi[j,n+1]+xi0[k]<=mu:


                    count[j]=count[j]+1/N
```

When I run this I get the error on the line `dC[j,n]=dC[j,n]+dC_frac[m]*dt` saying

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I'm new to python but I know that python indexing starts from 0, but I cant understand why this code stops here.

Comment: What exactly is `dC`?  You never initialize it in the code you posted.  I suspect it's an ordinary Python list (instead of a numpy array), in which case `dC[j,n]` is not valid  (you'd have to use `dC[j][n]` for multidimensional indexing).

Comment: Printing data, (conditional) expression results, anything relevant,  is an effective debugging technique.  You can print stuff just before the offending line or [catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print in the except suite. It will give you more clues to what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code is not complete. But I think the bug is clear.

By defining

```
 dC_frac=np.zeros((1,3))
```

You `dC_frac` is a *multidimensional* array of shape `(1,  3)`. Use `dC_frac.shape` you will find it's `(1, 3)`, *not*, `(3,)`.

Thus in

```
for m in range(0,3):
    dC_frac[m]=fraction[m]*E[j,n+1]-dC_memory[m]/(tauC[m])
    ...
```

Your `dC_frac[m]` is an array of 3 elements, *not* a scalar.

If your `dC[j, n]` and `dt` are scalars,

```
dC[j,n]=dC[j,n]+dC_frac[m]*dt
```

This will assign an array of 3 elements to an entry. Thus the error.

To fix, just use

```
dC_memory=np.zeros(3)
dC_frac=np.zeros(3)
```